# Display Small Image of Arabic Word in Android

Tags: java, android

i am new in android development community.
i want display small Arabic image (word) to make complete line.
which type of layout need to display small image to complete line.i have use grid view but image height and width are different.please share some piece of code or useful link

Comment: `i want display small Arabic image (word) to make complete line.` Can you make this concept clear? What did you try?

Comment: Frank N. Stein! i have Arabic image words.Like A,B,C,D.. etc and i need to display ABCD.but in my case in arabic word.here link that i want.   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sa.edu.ksu.Ayat&hl=en

Comment: First, `A, B, C, D` aren't **words**. They are **characters**. Second, why aren't you using a **font**, instead of images?

Comment: Frank N. Stein! thanks your reply.yes you are right.these are character.in my case i want to display word by using Arabic Character then i will select it and read it by word or line or whole page.can have any idea that is perfect for me.

Comment: What stops you using Arabian in your text? Android supports Arabian and RTL (Right To Left) direction.

Comment: i have used  Arabic image character and want to make these images into words.Like  these character  http://www.google.com.pk/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ukindia.com%2Fzar52.gif&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ukindia.com%2Fzar5.htm&h=548&w=688&tbnid=SLLHWlywO0jpEM%3A&zoom=1&docid=ECwx_-xqYFus4M&ei=86_5U_fuEMThaMzJgPgO&tbm=isch&ved=0CC4QMygAMAA&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=902&page=1&start=0&ndsp=20

Comment: It's not a good idea to use images in place of text, if you can use text... often you do the opposite (use fonts to represent images). Because fonts are **scalable** and you don't need to provide a bunch of images for every possible resolution. And your app size will grow a lot, when using images.

Comment: share please some help full tutorial or helpful link related Arabic fonts

Comment: Android font already supports Arabic. Just write in Arabic in your `/res/values-ar/strings.xml`. Be sure to use the UTF-8 Unicode encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use LinearLayout and add your words pragmatically as image height and width are different so you must add your words in a dynamic way.

In you activity layout put this.

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/view_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/splitter"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

               <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <!-- as they are added to and removed from the LinearLayout. -->

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/container_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                        android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:showDividers="middle" />
                </ScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>
```

// also make another layout for view_list_item and change it as your needs

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <com.csdc.crsmofa.views.TextViewNaskhRegular
        android:id="@+id/item_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textAppearance="@style/LoginTextViewAppearnce" />

    <com.csdc.crsmofa.views.TextViewNaskhRegular
        android:id="@+id/item_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/item_label"
        android:lines="1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

// In your activity

```
onCreate(...){
ViewGroup containerView = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.container_view);
fillView(containerView);


}



private void fillView(final ViewGroup mContainerView) {
                try {


mContainerView.removeAllViews();

ViewGroup newView = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater
                                    .from(getActivity())
                                    .inflate(R.layout.view_list_item, mContainerView, false);

                            ((TextView) newView.findViewById(R.id.item_label))
                                    .setText(R.string.need_reply_view);
                            ((TextView) newView.findViewById(R.id.item_text))
                                    .setText(correspondence.isNeedReply() ? R.string.yes_dialog
                                            : R.string.no_dialog);

mContainerView.addView(newView, 0); 

} catch (Exception ex) {
                String string = ex != null ? ex.getMessage() : "";
                Log.e(TAG, string != null ? string : "");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

Comment: Mohamed Fadl Allah! please share complete sample code on http://github.com/ thanks for help .